# How to delete in a DB using a comparation with NodeJS and Sequelize

Tags: node.js

I would like to be able to execute a function every so often that it will look in the database and delete all the tables that have already expired, that is, where the condition is met that the current date is greater than the expiration date, but I don't know how express it with the clauses that we use in nodejs and sequelize, then I leave you the idea of what I want to do but I don't know how to write the syntax correctly.
Here is the code (INCORRECT!!!):

```js
cron.schedule('0 0 */1 * * *', () => {
  const date = new Date();
  CodePassword.destroy({where: {
    expiration_date < date
  }})
});
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to do it please I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it:

```js
import pkg from "sequelize";
const { Op } = pkg;

cron.schedule('0 0 */1 * * *', () => {
  const date = new Date();
  CodePassword.destroy({
    where: {
      expiration_date: {
        [Op.lt]: date
      }
    }
  })
});
```